# Comparing a text from a EditText with an array of string characters

Tags: java, android

I am trying to compare a text taken from an `EditText` box -

```
edittext.getText().toString()
```

with an array of String characters

```
String[] alphabets = {"a","b",........"z"}
```

I want to compare each character from the editText box's string with the array characters so I can change the position of one character with another(in the text taken from  editText). 
So how can I do it? Or is there any other better way for this? 
Simply I just want to know how to compare each charater of a string

`edittext.getText().toString()` with an array of `String[] alphabets = {"a","b",........"z"}`.

1. What is the better way to parse a `string` to an `int`. Like if I get the text from an editText box and I want it to be an Integer, how do I do it.

I am asking this question because I have to implement an encryption algorithm called `Modular Arithmetic/Mathematics`
Thanks

Comment: Err, if I didn't misunderstand your question, you want to convert a character to number value, like a = 1, b = 2, etc? (`String` cannot be converted to `int` anyway). You can use `charAt()` to get a character on specific index, or `getBytes()` to convert to array of bytes.

Comment: For Parsing you can use - Integer intvalue=Integer.parseInt("123");

Comment: yes and no. I have a textbox and I get a value from it like textbox.getText()(remember that that value will always be a number). How do I have to do  to get that value as Int

Comment: @SaadZaheer Did you check my suggestion?

Comment: You didn't say that the input will be string *number* and given the alphabet array and comparing to it, I assume the input will be alphabetic. I did really misunderstand your question.

Comment: You really did. And so did everyone else which is why I lost some reputation(like it was already very high). Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Parsing you can use -

```
String editValue=edittext.getText().toString();
    Integer intvalue=Integer.parseInt(editValue);
```